# How to check if cells in a row are equal to another row in other sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

So I have 2 sheets being for example:

### Sheet1:

```
-------------
|   | A | B |
-------------
| 1 | x | y |
-------------
| 2 | z | w |
-------------
```

### Sheet2:

```
-------------
|   | A | B |
-------------
| 1 | n | u |
-------------
|...|...|...|
-------------
| 7 | x | y |
-------------
```

I want to check (like vlookup) if Sheet1's A1 is in Sheet2 A column and if it is check if next cell from Sheet2 (lets say it encounters in A7, check if B7 is equal to Sheet1's B1) is equal to Sheet1's B1 return true if encounters equal row and else if it doesn't. Also I know Sheet1 positioning but not Sheet2

### Update

So, I've been looking and trying and I manage to come up with a formula that makes sense to me but somehow it is not working:

```
=IF(SD!A2 = Spectrum!A:A & SD!B2 = INDEX(Spectrum!B:B,MATCH(SD!A2,Spectrum!A:A,0)) & SD!C2 = INDEX(Spectrum!C:C,MATCH(SD!A2,Spectrum!A:A,0)), "True", "False")
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with it, only returns false and i've looked in the sheets and it should return true.

Comment: You need countifs.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on your explanation.  You gave examples of 2 sheets, but what kind of **result** (output) would you expect, using that sample data?

Comment: @ashleedawg I told in the question return true or false. if cell An and Bn from one Sheet is equal to Ar and Br from another Sheet

Answer (score 0):

In C1 of Sheet2 and copied down to suit:

```
=AND(A1=Sheet1!A$1,B1=Sheet1!B$1)
```

returns FALSE except in Row7 (and any other rows in that sheet where the 'A' value is`x` and the 'B' value is `y`).

Answer (score 0):

try an array formula:
=SUM(IF(A1=Sheet2!A:A,IF(Sheet1!B1=Sheet2!B:B,1,0),0))

obvs use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to edit complete the cell entry

Results in 1 if true and 0 if false

The above array formula does refer to B in both sheets so the references are cross checked.    The result is the 1 or 0 and this satisfies the query of checking the existence of the value in the alternate sheet

Comment: Thank you for your awnser but it doesn't look on if(B) in the exact row of A i can have the same values in different rows and it would give me true anyway.

Comment: its an array formala so needs to be entered using the control+shift+enter keys for it to correctly function. Tried in worksheets here and it appears to be working for multiple rows of the target data source columns. If the combination appears on multiple rows then the return value will produce the total sum but that can easily be resolved into 'True/false'

Comment: your resulting array formula - in cell - should look like this: {=SUM(IF(A1=Sheet2!A:A,IF(Sheet1!B1=Sheet2!B:B,1,0),0))}